# Как выровнять text и конку внутри блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass

немогу додуматься как выровнять по центру иконку и текст после нее, пока получается так: 
[image: Плохо]

а надо так:
[image: Хорошо]

Код здесь https://jsfiddle.net/5zpkv2ry/1/

```
.dropdown__info__checkbox
                text-align: start
                width: 100%
                height: 100% 
                margin-top: 20px                                      
                .material-icons
                    display: flex
                    vertical-align: middle
                    padding-right: 20px
            .hide__info
                display: none
                width: 100%
            .information
                display: none
                padding: 15px
            .information div
                display: flex     
            .hide__info:checked + label + .information
                display: block 
                background: #ffffff
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)
                border-radius: 5px                             
            .hide__info + label                
                display: flex
                justify-content: flex-start
                border: 1px solid #ffffff
                width: 100%
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)
                height: 50px
                border-radius: 5px
            &__checkbox label
                cursor: pointer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо бы вам хотя бы основы js изучить, код сильно упрощает. Ну а пока вот -
https://jsfiddle.net/2z0mtxkr/1/

```css
.dropdown__info
            
            .dropdown__info__checkbox
                text-align: start
                width: 100%
                height: 100% 
                margin-top: 20px
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2)
                .material-icons
                    display: flex
                    vertical-align: middle
                    padding: 0 12px
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2)
                    line-height: 50px
                    
            .hide__info
                display: none
                width: 100%
            .information
                display: none
                padding: 15px
            .information div
                display: flex     
            .hide__info:checked + label + .information
                display: block 
                background: #ffffff
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)
                border-radius: 5px                             
            .hide__info + label                
                display: flex
                justify-content: flex-start
                border: 1px solid #ffffff
                width: 100%
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)
                height: 50px
                border-radius: 5px
                line-height: 50px
            &__checkbox label
                cursor: pointer
```

Comment: Вы не правы, хороший CSS это тот который можно выполнить без JS

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)